# Estimate a parameter that is not in a PDF, makes sense?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation

I have been reading some posts about the proof of the invariance of MLE because I did not fully understood the proof given in Statistical inference by Casella Berger in the page 320.

My doubt is the following... if we want to estimate a parameter should not that parameter be in model? **The Maximum Likelihood Estimators method assumes that the parameter is explicity in the probabilistic model.**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4c37.png) is the start of the proof and the transformation is $\eta=\tau(\theta)$.

To be precise my question is, shouldn't

$$\text{L(}\eta|X)$$

be the function to maximize instead of the function $\text{L(}\theta|X)$?

Comment: Is the function $\tau$ invertible? If so $\theta = \tau^{-1}(\eta)$.

Comment: It is made no assumption @Ben

Comment: This might come down to the distinction between "parameter" and "property."  The former is a special kind of property of a distribution that is used to identify the distribution (within a given family).  A property is a number that depends on the distribution (subject to some technical requirements; namely, that it should be a "nice" function of the distributions).  Properties of distributions are no more explicit than are properties of people: even though your name might be "6oncvlo," you have many more properties than are explicit in your name!

Comment: Some distributions can be parameterized in various ways. Are the parameters of a normal distribution $\mu, \sigma$ or $\mu, \sigma^2;$ the parameter of an exponential distribution may be the rate $\lambda$ or the mean $\mu = 1/\lambda;$ and so on. // According to the invariance principle of maximum likelihood estimation, if $S$ is an MLE for $\sigma,$ then $S^2$ is an MLE for $\sigma^2.$ And if $\bar X$ is MLE for exponential $\mu,$ then $1/\bar X$ is MLE for $\lambda.$ Of course, unbiasedness is another matter: $S^2$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2,$ not $S$ for $\sigma.$ ...

Comment: ... Also, $\bar X$ is unbiased for $\mu,$ but $1/\bar X$ is not unbiased for $\lambda.$ // In your question, you need to make clear what you mean by "in the model."

Comment: @BruceET What I meant by 'model'  is the probabilistic model, that for a random sample is the same as the likelihood function, $L(\theta | X)=f(X| \theta)$ where $f(X| \theta)$ is the pdf.

Comment: Some mathematical trivialities are germane. Let $L:\Theta\to\mathbb R$ be any real-valued function defined on any set $\Theta.$ Suppose $\hat\theta\in \Theta$ maximizes $L:$ that is, $L(\theta)\le L(\hat\theta)$ for all $\theta\in\Theta.$ Given any function $t:\Theta\to\Theta$ for which $\hat\theta$ is in the image of $t,$ the function $L\circ t$ (defined by $(L\circ t)(\eta)=L(t(\eta))$) is maximized at any $\hat\eta\in \Theta$ for which $t(\hat\eta)=\hat\theta.$ If $\hat\theta$ is a unique maximizer and there is only one $\hat\eta$ with $t(\hat\eta)=\hat\theta,$ then $\hat\eta$ is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a single observation $x$ from an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda.$ Then the likelihood function (PDF viewed as a function of $\lambda>0)$ for observed $x,$ is $f(x|\lambda) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x).$  It is clear from the figure below
that if $x = 5,$ then the likelihood function is maximized for $\lambda = 1/x = 0.2.$

```
x = 5
lam = seq(.0001, 2, by=0.0001)
like = lam * exp(-lam * x)
plot(lam, like, type="l")
 abline(v = 1/x, col="red", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 0, col="green2")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]

By contrast, consider a single observation $x$ from an exponential distribution with mean $\mu.$ Then the likelihood function (PDF viewed as a function of $\mu>0)$ for observed $x,$ is $f(x|\mu) = (1/\mu) \exp(- x/\mu).$ Now, it is clear from the figure below that if $x = 5$
that the likelihood function is maximized for $\mu = x = 5.$

```
x = 5
mu = seq(.0001, 30, by=0.0001)
like = (1/mu)* exp(-x/mu)
plot(mu, like, type="l", lwd=2)
 abline(v = x, col="red", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 0, col="green2")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]